# Where Clause with Less/Greater than after a Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, activerecord, where-clause

I'm trying to combine a `joins` with a `where` clause but the `where` clause is not testing an equality, it is testing for greater than or equal.

I know in a standard where clause, I can just do this:

```
Group.where("vote_deadline_at <= ?", Time.now)
```

to find all groups whose vote deadline is in the future.

However, what if this comes after a `joins`, like this:

```
User.likes.where(liked_type: "Post").joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = liked_id").where(posts: {context_type:"Group"}).joins("INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = posts.context_id").where(groups: {"vote_deadline_at <= ?",Time.now})
```

Everything up to the final `where(groups: {"vote_deadline_at <= ?",Time.now})` clause works fine. It returns an ActiveRecord collection of 186 rows. However, when I add the final `where` clause, I get the error:

```
SyntaxError: unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
...ote_deadline_at <= ?",Time.now})
```

Is there any way to further filter my results with a where clause that selects only rows where `groups.vote_deadline_at` is in the future (i.e. less than or equal to Time.now)?

Answer (score 2):

I thought I had tried this before, but apparently this syntax works:

```
u.likes.where(liked_type: "Post").joins("INNER JOIN posts ON posts.id = liked_id").where(posts: {context_type:"Group"}).joins("INNER JOIN groups ON groups.id = posts.context_id").where("groups.vote_deadline_at <= ?",Time.now)
```

I got exactly the results I expected.

Answer (score -2):

The syntax should be:
  `... .where(groups: ["vote_deadline_at <= ?",Time.now] )`