# How to filter future records in joined tables in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query that joins two models and then filters on the basis of `response_deadline`:

`Delivery.joins(:tendering_requests).where(tendering_requests: { response_deadline: 2.days.from_now })`

Instead of `2.days.from_now`, I want to filter the deliveries where the `response_deadline`s are after **whatever the date and time is right now**

Here, `response_deadline` is a datetime type, for eg, `Tue, 31 Jul 2018 10:51:19 EDT -04:00`

How can I filter them so that it shows only future deliveries?

If I had just one model I could do something like:

`TenderingRequest.where("response_deadline > ?", Time.now)` but how to filter when there are two models joined?

Comment: `Delivery.joins(:tendering_requests).where("tendering_requests.response_deadline > ?", Time.now)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested I can do: `Delivery.joins(:tendering_requests).where("tendering_requests.response_deadline >= ?",Time.now)`

Also, for more ref: [Where Clause with Less/Greater than after a Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42521885/where-clause-with-less-greater-than-after-a-join)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Delivery.joins(:tendering_requests).where("tendering_requests.response_deadline >= ?",Time.zone.now")
```